# Editing an Mailbox configuration file

Tags: macos

I want to use Sublime Text to edit a text file within one of my installed Applications. The application I am trying to edit is [Mailbox](http://www.mailboxapp.com/download/mac/). I have been trying to edit the following file - `/Applications/Mailbox (Beta).app/Contents/Resources/compose.css.txt`. I have been trying to rewrite the css on lines 21 to 25

```css
body {
   background-color: transparent;
   font-family: "Helvetica Neue", san-serif;
   font-size: 14px;
   margin:0; }
```

When I change the typeface to comic sans for example, mailbox stops functioning. Is there a way to make this change without corrupting the application?

An image of the error after editing the txt file has been embedded below;

[image: Mailbox is corrupted]

Comment: On hold pending additional information. It sounds like you're corrupting the settings file when you edit it; making invalid edits. What's the app, what edits are you trying to make to the file? The question really appears to be more about how you make valid file edits for this application and less about ST2.

Comment: I vote to reopen this question.

Answer (score 1):

From what I could tell, Mailbox now stays open after it displays the message, and crashes.

Since the crash had a bunch of JSON processes in it, I figured maybe that the lines were encoded, and since Comic Sans MS does not have the same number of letters as Helvetica Neue, I figured that was the problem. I then changed Neue to Bold, and made it the same number of letters.

Since it stil crashed, I believe it is not actually corrupted. I believe there is a encoded hash, or some sort, in the binary. Since the edit changed the hash, that may be the problem.

TL;DR: It is not possible unless you patch the binary in some way.